# What is a concise book for learning PDE at master's level?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I am looking for a book that is organized concisely (says a lot using little words), that presents need-to-know introductory PDE concepts, and quickly transitions into masters-like material

Some examples of books in other topics:

- *Complex Analysis*: "Complex Analysis" by M.W. Wong
- *Winding Number*: "Winding Around: The Winding Number in Topology, Geometry, and Analysis" by John Roe

Comment: Did you have a look at *Partial Differential Equations* by Lawrence C. Evans? 
Although the book itself is rather lengthy (as mentioned by enzotib), its individual chapters provide a concise treatment of the topics covered.

Comment: @fsp-b Thank you, given the length, this a good suggestion especially if it becomes apparent that PDE's are crucial to my main studies. I will keep this in the memory bank